# Get a character from a string value?

Tags: assembly, arm

I have a set of numbers in a string (in memory) as follows:

```
numbers     DCB "012345"
```

How can I access that first digit and insert it into a register?

I would load it right, but I am unsure how to load that specific digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to load the first digit into a register:

```
ldrb r0, numbers
```

r0 now contains the value 48 (ASCII '0')

To load the address of `numbers` into a register and then load  from it, do this:

```
ldr r0, =numbers    // r0 now contains the address of numbers
ldrb r1, [r0]
```

r1 also now contains the value 48

You can load specific digits (e.g. the 3rd digit) like this:

```
ldr r0, =numbers
add r0, #2
ldrb r1, [r0]
```

or like this:

```
ldr r0, =numbers
ldrb r1, [r0, #2]
```

or like this:

```
ldr r0, =numbers
mov r1, #2
ldrb r2, [r0, r1]
```

P.S. if you want the string to be null-terminated you need to declare it like this:

```
numbers     DCB "012345", 0
```

or, depending on your assembler, like this:

```
numbers:
    .asciz "012345"
```

Comment: Incredible. I will post here if I run into trouble, thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to work with these ascii characters, like add them? If I add them as is, I get unexpected results.

Comment: subtract the ASCII value for '0' from the char to get the value it represents e.g. sub r1, r1, #48. then you can add etc. add 48 to convert the other way. if you want to do more complicated arithmetic beyond a single digit you'll have to do a string to int conversion taking the place value of each digit (1, 10, 100) etc into account